# Stripe.js V3 - prohibit double click (Enter key)

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

Hello and Happy New Year everyone.

I integrated Stripe.js on my Web App (PHP 7 / Laravel 5).

I use the V3 : Stripe.js and Elements : https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

```
   var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#payment-form button').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#payment-form button').css('cursor', 'not-allowed');

        // ...
    });
```

This allows me to disable the double click on the form button.

But if the user presses the enter key twice, the form is submitted twice...

Just after the submit, how can I disable the input type text created by stripe ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is making use of the [element.update(options)](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#other-methods) function

`card.update({disabled: true/false});`

in this case, the card input should be disabled, but you will need to remember to reenable it if there is any errors coming back from backend.

Comment: Thank you very much